# How can I get .NET Console Logs from Azure App Service to Azure Event Hub?

Tags: .net, azure, logging, serilog, azure-eventhub

I have a .NET 6 project writing application logs to Console using Serilog. The app is hosted on a Windows App Service.

Setup like this:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
        .Enrich.FromLogC1ontext()
        .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate);
```

I have setup a Diagnostic Setting on the App Service to send the logs from Console Output to the Event Hub, but no console logs are sent to Event Hub.

I have also tried enabling HttpLogs, which work fine. So the trigger is working, but how do I get the stdout/Console logs to work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because, [**`AppServiceConsoleLogs`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#supported-log-types) are not supported by .net windows application. Supported only for JavaSE and Tomcat.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. But how do you get logs from .NET apps?